# How can i add a new object property to existing object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, let's say `array[object,object....]` . I want to add a new property to each object inside an array. 
Below i have mentioned and existing array and the resulted one which i want.

Existing array :

```
array[ {"name":"Siddhesh mishra","add":"hjhjjdjkhjibf",}
       {"name":"Brijesh mishra","add":"jkfhgfbrfhiurf"} ]
```

I want this array :

```
array[ {"name":"Siddhesh mishra","add":"hjhjjdjkhjibf","mobile":"95937338373"}
       {"name":"Brijesh mishra","add":"jkfhgfbrfhiurf","mobile":"78984983498"} ]
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Your question says "push one value to *first* object inside an array", but the explanation says you want to add properties to *every* object.

Comment: @tavnab Would you help me out for this

Comment: Please update your question on which you're trying to accomplish; add to _first_ or add to _every_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this. Let there be an array of mobile number whose length is same as the length of `array`. Loop through the `array` array and add the `mobile` key and value from `mobNum` array

```js
var mobNum=[1,2];
var array = [{
  "name": "Siddhesh mishra",
  "add": "hjhjjdjkhjibf"
}, {
  "name": "Brijesh mishra",
  "add": "jkfhgfbrfhiurf"
}]
array.forEach(function(item,index){
  item.mobile=mobNum[index]
})
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [ {"name":"Siddhesh mishra","add":"hjhjjdjkhjibf"},
       {"name":"Brijesh mishra","add":"jkfhgfbrfhiurf"} ];


data.map(function(entry){
  //add logic to get mobile number from entry.name or entry.add
  return entry.mobile = '98989898';
})

console.log(data);
```

Comment: I think you need a `var test =` before your `data.map`

Comment: `map()` is not the right iteration tool for this if you aren't actually returning a new array